# What assembler would be best fit to program an OS from scratch, with execution performance prioritized?

Tags: performance, assembly, operating-system, portability

**I am not fit to program an OS under any circumstances, but this is hypothetical.**

I want to create a simple operating system from almost absolute scratch in assembly language. With great ambitions in mind, I want it to be as optimized as possible for execution. I also want the code to be fairly portable for multiple architectures (especially x86 and x64 interchangeably). I feel a bit minimalist, so lets toss out software "bloat".

What I am looking for is an assembler that can fit this criteria. Obviously, I want one that is decently documented officially or unofficially, and I need it to be decently well-known (I.E. I don't want "ΣASM" found in the middle of the internet Sahara.)

Comment: ugh... dont end up in that internet sahara yourself, there are people who believed the same when writing those assemblers!

Comment: Sorry, but you have to realize that it's *you* to optimize your assembly code, not the assembler. Assemblers translate the textual representation of instructions into the binary representation understood by the CPU, they do a pretty much 1-to-1 translation without trying to be smart or smarter than you are. If you write lousy assembly code, you get a lousy executable out of it. That's the nature of assembly programming.

Comment: Consult the [MenuetOS](http://www.menuetos.net/) project. They've alread built a functioning OS with GUI in assembly language.

Answer (score 3):

Under the circumstances you specify, NASM would probably be the best choice. It's reasonably well documented, fairly widely used and heavily tested. It's also one of the few that can directly produce raw binary output files, where most require that you jump though hoops with the linker to get that. This isn't so much an issue for the OS proper as it is for the bootloader, but (for whatever reason) most who work on an OS themselves also write at least a few toy bootloaders as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are contradicting yourself greatly.  Optimizing for execution on x86 is not possible, each family can/does execute the same binary at dramatically different speeds, esp if you are going to jump between 32 bit and 64 bit.  If your goal is speed on an x86 do not write in asm, use C, then let the compiler optimize for the platform it happens to be on.  for large projects you are not going to be able to compete with the compiler.  For short compiler generated code sequences, yes, sure you can sometimes hand assemble something better/faster.  for x86 the compiler is likely to do a better job at average good speed on an x86 than you are.  Bloat doesnt necessarily come from the compilers or language but from the design and implementation in whatever language chosen.  Very very easy to have bloated asm as bloated C or other.

Second, if you are writing in assembly language.  How much of this code is instructions and how much do you expect to be assembler specific directives and other nuances?  You can at least attempt to write somewhat portable asm that works on different assemblers using a minimum number of directives shared by those assemblers, the rest being instructions.  x86 unfortunately has problems here as well, there is the intel vs at&t syntax problem to start with then the byte ptr and near/far items to tell the assembler which flavor of a particular instruction which even limited to intel syntax may not be portable from one x86 assembler to another.  You can get a raspberry pi for $25 or a beaglebone for $90.

x86 assembly is dreadful at best, decades of band-aids on top of band-aids (starting with the original which was predecessor+bandaids).  If you feel the need to do a good sized assembly project, (vs something more useful like C) esp if speed is your goal, then choose a better processor and instruction set.  I dont know the size of your project.  If small enough then thumb or thumb2 or arm or avr or msp430, if larger then arm or mips.  Sadly enough for most of those you would probably go with gnu binutils.  For x86 if you really think you need to use that instruction set and that hardware for this, I agree with Jerry, go with nasm.